# Adverb after very much

Tags: adverbs

> You helped me very much again.

Is this sentence correct? If it is correct, does it sound kind of odd?

Comment: It sounds find. If you feel awkward saying it, you could move the "again" to the front of the sentence.

Comment: You can say “muchly” if you like. ;-)  https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/muchly

Answer (score -1):

Grammatically, it’s correct. But it can be worded better.